# Css box fluidity issue

Tags: css, fluid

I have been trying to make fluid boxes that will squeeze when you resize the window.

but this is whats happening:

When I resize the window the 4th box moves to the bottom and then the width of the boxes shrink. why is the 4th box moves under? what am I doing wrong?

Here's is whats happening:
http://www.dinkypage.com/169785

Here's the source:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4ZbbXxCq

Help Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you give the `width: 25%` to all 4 block, but also give 'padding: 10px' to them so obviously the width need to take more than `100%`.

You need to either remove your padding or reduce the width of your block less than the total length of your padding, for example `22%`

Comment: And use padding with values in percentage, too

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `box-sizing: border-box`. This is because the padding of 10px you have assigned to each of the floated div elements are added on top of the 25% width you have assigned, so the actual sum of the width of all four floated divs will exceed 100% (in fact, it will be 100% + (2*10px)*4 = 100% + 80px

The `box-sizing: border-box` property will ensure that the height and width you have set for the element will also include the paddings (if any) and/or border widths (if any).

In fact, I would suggest [Paul Irish's recommendation](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) using:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Since you also have your height explicitly declared, you might want to change the height of the containers to reflect the change in the box model. Since you have a padding-top of 30px and now it will be computed as part of the height of 240px, you should change the height to 240px + 30px (top padding) + 10px (bottom padding) = 280px.